# How to get connection name used by the Windows Network adapter?

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

Is it possible get it using WMI query?

my current code:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
                                       "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapte");

foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
{
     Console.WriteLine(queryObj[??]);        
}
```

I'm tried get the connections name from:

```
Control Panel \ Network and Internet \ Network Connections
```

Comment: You probably want the `Name` property of Win32_NetworkConnection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using code below you would be able dump all properties of the Network Adapter, you need `Name` property:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(
    "SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter");

foreach (ManagementObject adapter in searcher.Get())
{
    StringBuilder propertiesDump = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var property in adapter.Properties)
    {
        propertiesDump.AppendFormat(
            "{0} == {1}{2}", 
            property.Name, 
            property.Value, 
            Environment.NewLine);        
    }
}
```

OR simply using LINQ (add `using System.Linq`):

```
foreach (ManagementObject adapter in searcher.Get())
{
   string adapterName = adapter.Properties
                               .Cast<PropertyData>()
                               .Single(p => p.Name == "Name")
                               .Value.ToString();
}
```

PS: Also be aware you've typo in WMI query - forgot `r` in `Adapter`: Win32_NetworkAdapte_r_

Answer (score 0):

Let's change the code a little more and shorten it. **ManagementClass** class shortens the WMI query.

```
ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapter");
ManagementObjectCollection results = mc.GetInstances();

foreach (var result in results)
{
    foreach (PropertyData data in result.Properties)
        Console.WriteLine($"{data.Name} == {data.Value}");
}
```